# js/jquery: scheduling events

Tags: javascript, events

I want to schedule events, that will fire and call my predefined callback

How can schedule in js / jquery:

1. one time event?
2. recurring event (to call my function every minute, or five minutes)?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You want  [`setTimeout`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WindowTimers.setTimeout) for a one time event and  [`setInterval`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WindowTimers.setInterval) for a repeating event.

Both take two arguments: a function and an interval of time specified in milliseconds.

```
var delay_millis = 1500;

//will alert once, at least half a second after the call to setTimeout
var onceHandle = window.setTimeout(function() {
  alert("Time has passed!");
}, delay_millis);

//will alert again and again
var repeatHandle = window.setInterval(function() {
  alert("Am I annoying you yet?");
}, delay_millis);
```

Bonus: if you keep around the values returned by calling these functions, you can cancel the callback if you need to.

```
var shutUpShutUp = function() {
  window.clearInterval(repeatHandle);
};

shutUpShutUp(); //now I can hear myself think.
```

Answer (score 2):

jQuery has nothing to do with it. You need JavaScript timers: `setTimeout()` and `setInterval()`

Answer (score 1):

A one-time event is just scheduled with a setTimeout call.  An easy way for a recurring event is to simply call setTimeout in the function that you are setting the timeout on.

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way to schedule events (at predefined intervals) is [`window.setTimeout`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/window.setTimeout).

For a one time event, you set the timeout once and let the timeout fire.

For recurring events, you set the timeout once and then reset the timeout in the method that gets called.

Answer (score 0):

You can bind a function to an event that will be run only once by using .one() in jQuery...

http://api.jquery.com/one/

For the problem of a timing threshold for an event, declare your event like this:

```
var clickAvailable = true;
$('#element').click(function(e) {
    if(!clickAvailable) {
       clickAvailable = false;
       //your code
       setTimeout(function() {
           clickAvailable = true;
       }, 5*60*1000); // 5 minutes...
    }
});
```